# Loading image using Picasso showing colors in corners

Tags: java, android, picasso, image-loading

I use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library for loading images in my app. But in some images,it shows a colored corner.See the red color in attached image. Does anyone know why this happens? How to sort this out?[image: See the red color here]

Code:

```
Picasso picasso = Picasso.with(getActivity());
        picasso.setDebugging(true);
        picasso.load(downloadPath+imgDetailPhoto)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.no_image)
                .error(R.drawable.no_image)
                .into(eventImage, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        Log.d("Error...", "picasso load error");
                        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(R.drawable.no_image).into(eventImage);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: Please see the updated question

Comment: set picasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(false); in your picasso object

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set `picasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(false);` in your picasso object.

**Red** color indicates that image is fetched from **network**.

**Green** color indicates that image is fetched from **cache memory**.

**Blue** color indicates that image is fetched from **disk memory**.

`picasso.setDebugging(true);` is **deprecated**

use `picasso.setLoggingEnabled(true);`

Comment: +! for the detailed answer. This solved my issue :) Thanks a ton dude :)

Answer (score 3):

you have to disable indicators by calling the method `picasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(false)`

the ribbon is mean to show the image source. hope it helps

check this [link](http://square.github.io/picasso/), under the **Debug Indicators** they've mentioned it clearly

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: There is no relation b/w debugging mode and indicators. Indicators only works if only you set setIndicatorsEnabled(true) not on debugging mode. checked on picasso 2.5.2.

Answer (score 2):

That's a debug indicator displayed by picasso to indicate whether the image is comming from the network, disk or memory. You can check it here http://square.github.io/picasso/ under 'Debug Indicators'

> For development you can enable the display of a colored ribbon which indicates the image source. Call setIndicatorsEnabled(true) on the Picasso instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)